# Copy shortcut operation with CRichEditCtrl in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, win32gui, mfc-feature-pack

I am very new to MFC. I am having following code for `Copy` and `SelectAll` shortcuts for `CRichEditCtrl` object.

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_COPY, OnCopy)
ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_SELECT_ALL, OnSelectAll)
```

But I am not able to catch breakpoint for Copy `(Ctrl+C)` and SelectAll `(Ctrl+A)` in the functions which I wrote here as It is not getting executed.

Here CRichEditCtrl object is read only(Text is for read and not allowed to modified).

I also want to provide functionality of Text Selection with Mouse for CRichEditCtrl object.

Any idea on How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actions are not executed with a WM_COMMAND value we know. Also the keystrokes are checked internally and handled internally.

Internally there are special window messages named WM_COPY and WM_PASTE for some actions that interact with the clipboard.

Afaik the selection (Select all) is done completely internal. you can try to subclass the RTF control and intercept the EM_SETSEL message.

If you want to intercept the keystrokes you can use PreTranslateMessage or you can again subclass the RTF control.

Comment: Any idea on how to do Text Selection with mouse for this read-only CRichEditCtrl object ?

Comment: Did you set it read only, oder did you use EnaleWindow? Inmy RTF controls I can use the mouse to select text. (EM_SETREADONLY)

Comment: It is Read only. Is there any way I can use EM_GETSEL in PreTranslateMessage() to get the selected text from CRichEditCtrl object.

Comment: AFAIK yes. What is your problem?

Comment: I want to Select Text with the help of Mouse which we see in other editors.

Comment: If have also read only RTF controls. And it is possible to select text with the mouse. I don't understand the problem, you have. May be you should start a new question.